# how can I get some attributes when using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

Here is my xml string, I want to get the English result "B"

```xml
  <body>
    <attributes>
      <attr name="Math" namespace="">A</attr>
      <attr name="English" namespace="" parentName="">B</attr>
    </attributes>
  </body>
```

Here is how I parse the xml string

```
result = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
res = Hash.from_xml(result.to_s)
```

But when I use `res["body"]["attributes"]`, I only get the result set

```
=> {"attr"=>["A", "B"]}
```

Because the order of attr is not regular，
So how can I judge what the English result really is ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selector:

```
result.css("attr[name='English']").children.to_s
```

will give you `"B"`

Comment: Thanks! It work! Now how to get the namespace of English, if there is a way to iterate the attr ?

Comment: `result.css("attr[name='English']")` will return the collection from which you can iterate.

`english = result.css("attr[name='English']"); english.first.attributes["namespace"].value # ""`